# $A$ is a cyclic group. $f_n : A→ A$, $f_n(a) = a^n$. Only homomorphism is $f_n$

Tags: group-theory

A is cyclic. For n in Z, let f<sub>n</sub> : A → A be f<sub>n</sub>(a) = a<sup>n</sup>. Only homomorphism is f<sub>n</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Every homomorphism of the cyclic group is defined by what it does to a generator. So say $g$  is a generator and that the homomorphism takes $g\to g'.$ Can we say that $g' = g^n$ for some $n$? Then show it follows that this homomorphism is $\phi_n$

Comment: I get this, but if the g in the question is not a generator (any g in G), is this still true?

Comment: @Lucas That's what my last sentence is asking you to prove. Maybe start with exploring the first sentence that a homomorphism is determined entirely by its action on a generator.